# angular 12 Universal, failling html validation with error on routerLink attribute

Tags: html, angular, dom, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

Any ideas what to do, with this error? `RouterLink` attribute fail W3 HTML validation?

The template is a simple HTML like

```
<a [routerLink]="data.levelOneUrl" >{{data.levelOneName}}</a>
```

[image]

Also, seems angular fail with all W3 validations, no just routerLink, but I have multiple issues with almost all attributes injected from angular

Comment: Well it should work, but make this change `<a [routerLink]="["properPath"]" >{{data.levelOneName}}</a>`. Also, when does it failing? Does angular is throwing an error?

Comment: Fail when the view-source is rendered from angular universal or SSR with Expressjs.

Comment: that fixed the issue, I am not sure, why angular is not validating this, I had multiple areas as
[routerLink]="data.levelOneUrl"
or
routerLink="data.levelOneUrl"

and all of them fail unless I use this structure [routerLink]="["properPath"]"

Comment: I believe you should use this notion to pass URL path.